# Simple function dosen't return what i want

Tags: python-2.7

I want this function to give me around 10 values split in 2 list, but it only gives me 1 value. Why?

```
import random
def chance():
  count = 0
  while count < 10:
    list11 = []
    list22 = []
    num = random.randint(1,11)
    if num > 6:
        list11.append(num)
    elif num < 6:
        list22.append(num)
    count += 1
print list11
print list22
```

chance()

Comment: Every time you loop, you clear both lists. Put 'list11=[]' and 'list22=[]' before the 'while' and it will work. With your current design you will only get the last value of 'num'

Comment: Your code, as shown, won't have `list1` or `list2` defined outside of `chance`.

Comment: I dont see any return statement?